# Strange syntax error involving block and ternary operator

Tags: ruby, block, ternary-operator

I tried  code similar to this:

```
array = [1, 2, 3]
array.each do |i|
  i == 1 ? puts "foo" : puts "bar"
end
```

but I got syntax errors saying:

```
expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
```

Then I tried code like this:

```
array = [1, 2, 3]
array.each do |i|
  puts i == 1 ? "foo" : "bar"
end
```

and it worked.

Why does that error occur? Is that a bug?

I found https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10653 about an bug with the ternary operator and a block but I can't understand much of it.

I'm using ruby 2.2.4

Comment: That is definitely the bug you're seeing.  Looks like it's a regression introduced in 2.2.

For "real" code, just use the latter - the ternary operator is more idiomatic when used for for assignment rather than control flow anyway.

Comment: @jjm This is not a bug it has to do with the fact that ruby allows you to omit parenthesis for method calls but only when they are the last item on the line. Since ternary is inline you would have to change to `i == 1 ? puts("foo") : puts("bar")` that being said the second is DRYer anyway. Otherwise the interpreter tries to deal with `puts("foo" : puts "bar")` and that is invalid syntax.

Comment: @engineersmnky Ok you're right - the syntax is always bogus without the parens.  The bug is that it reports something about a missing `do`, which is confusing.

Comment: @jjm `do` is valid block syntax and any method can be passed a block it just may never `call` or `yield` to it. The parser does not make this discrimination thus it reponds with all the options that could be valid to fix the syntax error `keyword_do or '{' or '('`

Comment: Ah, right you are.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug, but an operator precedence issue
`i == 1 ? puts "foo" : puts "bar"` reads to Ruby as `i == 1 ? puts("foo" : puts "bar")` which doesn't make sense. This happens because method call has the lowest precedence among all the operators

Instead you should put the parenthesis by yourself as in `i == 1 ? puts("foo") : puts("bar")`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Ruby is having trouble evaluating those two expressions.

Try wrapping them in parenthesis:

```
array = [1, 2, 3]
array.each do |i|
  i == 1 ? (puts "foo") : (puts "bar")
end
```

which should work.

Comment: This is also a case where a ternary is awfully messy. When making method calls, use a proper `if` to break out the logic and make it very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use parenthesis when calling a method:

```
array = [1, 2, 3]
array.each do |i|
  i == 1 ? puts("foo") : puts("bar")
end
```

> explicit is better than implicit